# Selecting specific controls when extracting from word to excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

Is it possible to select which specific form controls are extracted from word to excel?

I have a macro at the moment that works fine and extracts all the form controls into excel, onto one single row. The thing is, I need to break down the controls into 3 different sections. Each having its own sheet/tab. The form controls are text and drop down lists.

For example: Say the form has 9 questions.

1st worksheet/tab, macro will pull questions
1.
2.
3.

2nd worksheet/tab, macro will pull questions (I don't mind a separate macro)
4.
5.
6.

3rd worksheet/tab macro will pull questions(I don't mind a separate macro)
7.
8.
9.

Current macro that runs great, but brings in every single control:

```
Sub GetFormData()
'Note: this code requires a reference to the Word object model
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim wdApp As New Word.Application, wdDoc As Word.Document, CCtrl As Word.ContentControl
Dim strFolder As String, strFile As String, WkSht As Worksheet, i As Long, j As Long
strFolder = GetFolder
If strFolder = "" Then Exit Sub
Set WkSht = ActiveSheet
i = WkSht.Cells(WkSht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
strFile = Dir(strFolder & "\*.docx", vbNormal)
While strFile <> ""
  i = i + 1
  Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(Filename:=strFolder & "\" & strFile, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)
  With wdDoc
    j = 0
    For Each CCtrl In .ContentControls
      With CCtrl
        Select Case .Type
          Case Is = wdContentControlCheckBox
           j = j + 1
           WkSht.Cells(i, j).Value = .Checked
          Case wdContentControlDate, wdContentControlDropdownList, wdContentControlRichText, wdContentControlText
           j = j + 1
           WkSht.Cells(i, j).Value = .Range.Text
          Case Else
        End Select
      End With
    Next
    .Close SaveChanges:=False
  End With
  strFile = Dir()
Wend
wdApp.Quit
Set wdDoc = Nothing: Set wdApp = Nothing: Set WkSht = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Function GetFolder() As String
Dim oFolder As Object
GetFolder = ""
Set oFolder = CreateObject("Shell.Application").BrowseForFolder(0, "Choose a folder", 0)
If (Not oFolder Is Nothing) Then GetFolder = oFolder.Items.Item.Path
Set oFolder = Nothing
End Function
```

Example of what it looks like. The questions are repeated so dont mind them:

[image]

Comment: FWIW `Dim wdApp As New Word.Application` is a bad idea. Try `Debug.Print wdApp Is Nothing` immediately after the `Set wdApp = Nothing` instruction, you'll see what I mean ;-)

Comment: Is it always going to be three sets of three? If not, you need to describe the required logic a bit more precisely...

Comment: @CindyMeister Nope, won't always be there. 1st set is a total of 12 questions. 2nd set of questions is a total 7 questions. 3rd set is a total of 8 questions

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Thank you Mathieu, I did what you recommended, but did not see any difference. :/

Comment: That `Debug.Print` statement would print `False` if you tried it, even after `Set wdApp = Nothing`. Auto-instantiated object variables, especially those that involve spawning a new process, should usually be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

Here 's an outline to approach what you want. Basically it's all in the set up. My solution assumes that each control in your Word document has the `Title` field set and defined to a unique value.

My suggestion is to isolate similarly coded logic into separate functions. As an example, the `SaveControlData` and `IsInArray`.

```
Option Explicit

Sub example()
    Dim thisSheet As Worksheet
    Dim thatSheet As Worksheet
    Dim theOtherSheet As Worksheet
    Set thisSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set thatSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set theOtherSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")

    '--- map the control (by Title) to each worksheet
    Dim thisTitles As Variant
    Dim thatTitles As Variant
    Dim theOtherTitles As Variant
    thisTitles = Split("MyCheckbox,MyTextbox", ",")
    thatTitles = Split("MyDatebox", ",")
    theOtherTitles = Split("MyCheckbox,MyDatebox", ",")

    Dim wdApp As Word.Application
    Set wdApp = New Word.Application

    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
    Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open("C:\Temp\Test text.docx")

    '--- determine the starting point for data on each worksheet
    Dim thisCell As Range
    Dim thatCell As Range
    Dim theOtherCell As Range
    Set thisCell = thisSheet.Range("A1")      'calculate last row?
    Set thatCell = thatSheet.Range("A1")
    Set theOtherCell = theOtherSheet.Range("A1")

    Dim CCtrl As Word.ContentControl
    With wdDoc
        For Each CCtrl In .ContentControls
            '--- arranging the If statements like this means you could
            '    technically copy the same control value to different
            '    worksheets
            If IsInArray(thisTitles, CCtrl.Title) Then
                SaveControlData thisCell, CCtrl
                thisCell.Offset(0, 1).value = CCtrl.Title
                Set thisCell = thisCell.Offset(1, 0)
            End If
            If IsInArray(thatTitles, CCtrl.Title) Then
                SaveControlData thatCell, CCtrl
                thatCell.Offset(0, 1).value = CCtrl.Title
                Set thatCell = thatCell.Offset(1, 0)
            End If
            If IsInArray(theOtherTitles, CCtrl.Title) Then
                SaveControlData theOtherCell, CCtrl
                theOtherCell.Offset(0, 1).value = CCtrl.Title
                Set theOtherCell = theOtherCell.Offset(1, 0)
            End If
        Next CCtrl
    End With

    wdDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False
    wdApp.Quit
End Sub

Private Function IsInArray(ByRef wordList As Variant, ByVal thisWord As String) As Boolean
    IsInArray = False
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(wordList, 1) To UBound(wordList, 1)
        If wordList(i) = thisWord Then
            IsInArray = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
End Function

Private Sub SaveControlData(ByRef cell As Range, ByRef CCtrl As Variant)
    With CCtrl
        Select Case .Type
            Case Is = wdContentControlCheckBox
                cell.value = .Checked
            Case wdContentControlDate, _
                 wdContentControlDropdownList, _
                 wdContentControlRichText, _
                 wdContentControlText
                cell.value = .Range.Text
            Case Else
        End Select
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: i will give this a go and report back. Thanks Peter.

Comment: I received a Compile Error when running this code "User-defined type not defined"

Comment: I suspect you need to [use early binding](https://peltiertech.com/Excel/EarlyLateBinding.html), so add the MS Word library reference via the Tools-->References menu.

Comment: Thanks. Running the macro prompts a "Subscript out of range" message.

Comment: As a tip -- make sure your worksheet names (in the tabs) are `Sheet1`, `Sheet2`, and `Sheet3` or change the example code above to match your own sheet names. Also update the strings that are `Split` into array with your own control titles.

Comment: you were definitely right about the sheet names. Adjusted those. I had forgot I had changed them. Re-ran the Macro, but no data in either spreadsheet (No errors). The issue is most likely what you mentioned about updating the strings with my own control titles. My controls don't have titles, they are just drop down menus and text boxes. Sounds like it is a misunderstanding from my end. I will post examples on my initial post.